# ListBucket vs ListObjects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-billing

Recently I have checked my AWS billing details in the CSV file. I was charged for the **ListBucket** operation. I have enabled CLoudTrail to understand who is making ListBucket requests. Using CloudTrail I could see only ListObject requests. But i was charged for ListBucket(under **line_item_operation** field in the CSV file).

Any difference between ListBucket and ListObjects?

Comment: I think ListBucket is deprecated.

Comment: I think IAM uses `s3:ListBucket` permissions to allow users to run `ListObjects()`, so it is quite confusing. So, think of them as being the same.

Answer (score 1):

List bucket is an operation that can specify either put/copy/post/list request to S3 (which can be done via the console itself, or a request from CLI/SDK), or a data transfer charge (inter region/bandwidth out).

You can definitely use the lineitem/usageType and lineitem/lineItemDescription to understand better the charges.

If you have it enabled - you can also use the AWS "CreatedBy" tag for cost reports that can show you if the charge is specific to a specific user/role.